# Inserting timestamp with timezone in text in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I created an insert statement that inserts the current time into a field with datatype:

> TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE

```
insert into(
...
)
values(
9645
,0
,CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)
,user
,CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)
,0
,'APPROVED_P'
,1
,1
)
```

This works fine, but for one problem

[image]

I would like to have the timezone in text as well, but I'm unable to find a solution. Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value, so your cast is useless. What is your problem? `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns time in current user session time zone, check value of `SESSIONTIMEZONE`. If you are looking for time in database server time zone use `SYSTIMESTAMP`. Or change time zone by `ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = '...'`

Comment: Yeah you are right, the cast is useless. Simply inserting CURRENT_TIMESTAMP would give the same result. As to what's my problem, The database value of the timezone is formatted as '+01:00' and I'd like to have it formatted as the other rows ('CET')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time zone `+01:00` is not the same as `CET`. Mayor difference is `CET` considers daylight saving times whereas `+01:00` does not.

If you want time zone `CET` then you must set your session time zone accordingly with `ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'CET';` or you set `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'CET'` instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

You should see the difference when you run this:

```
SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE, 
    TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss tzh:tzm tzr tzd'),
    TO_CHAR((current_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '6' MONTH), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss tzh:tzm tzr tzd')
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining. I thought +01:00 and CET were the same, so I learned something! CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'CET' does the job perfectly, thank you.

Comment: Be aware in summer you may get an unwanted time shift, depending on how your session time zone is set. Better change your session time zone to `CET` or use `SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'CET'` . You can set default time zone also be environment variable `ORA_SDTZ` or in Registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_<Oracle Home Name>\ORA_SDTZ` / `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_<Oracle Home Name>\ORA_SDTZ`